# Swift open datepicker at bottom with done and cancel button when i click label

Tags: swift, uilabel

I am making application in iphone using swift and following code

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    //<#code#>
    dateSet.userInteractionEnabled = true
    let aSelector : Selector = "lblTapped"
    let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: aSelector)
    tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1

    dateSet.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
}



func lblTapped(){
 // need to add datapicker UIView
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use textfield `inputView` for datepicker to display at bottom. Sample code below

private func dateTextFieldSetup()

```
    {
        let datePickerView  : UIDatePicker = UIDatePicker()
    datePickerView.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.Date
    sampleTextfield.inputView = datePickerView
    datePickerView.addTarget(self, action:#selector(CFTextField.handleDatePickerForSlectedText(_:)), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)

}
```

For UILabel inputView property is not available.